# How to increase pagesize temporarily?

Tags: mongodb, restheart

Just for testing purpose I would like to get 100 , 500 , 1000 , 5000 , 10000 , 20000 ... records from a Collection. At the moment the largest pagesize is 1000. How can I increase it to whatever I would like for just testing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTHeart has a pagesize limit of 1000 pages per request and that's hardcoded into class `org.restheart.handlers.injectors.RequestContextInjectorHandler`.

If you, for any reason, want to increase that limit then you have to change the source code and build your own jar.

However, RESTHeart speedups the execution of GET requests to collections resources via its *db cursors pre-allocation engine*. This applies when several documents need to be read from a big collection and moderates the effects of the MongoDB cursor.skip() method that slows downs linearly. So it already optimizes the navigation of large MongoDB collections, if this is what you are looking for.

Please have a look at [Speedup Requests with Cursor Pools](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/h4CM) and [Performances](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/gICM) page in the official documentation for more information.